# Celery tasks stuck in RECEIVED state after execution

Tags: python, celery

Celely + rabbitmq as backend 
Simple task which only makes one update request to database.
This task is executed periodically in batches (about 5 at once).
Sometimes 1 or 2 of them stays in RECEIVED state but updates to database are actually finished succesfully.
Seems these tasks are just stuck before or even after returning result.

Comment: did you find out something about this?

Comment: Still experiencing the same problem. Is there a solution?